# Reading a file path from xml path in a jar file

Tags: java, xml, jar

I have implemented a java program which runs fine. However, when I convert it to jar, it complains about the file path in a xml file.

I am using some external libraries and files. I specify the location of these files in a xml file. I use getClass().getResourceAsStream("xml file")); to load the xml file. However I have a path location mentioned inside the xml file where some external files are located. This location also has some sub folders. I tried placing them in the same directory as the source code, but it still complaints about the same.

How should I change the location in the xml file or where should I move the external file?

I have the following structure:

```
src
-main
--java
---package
----class file(source)
----xml file
----dict
-----unix
------All important files that need to be found
```

EDIT

---

XML file is as below:

```
<param name="file_manager"
            value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl">
            <param name="file_type"
                value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile" />
            <param name="dictionary_path" value="dict/unix" />
        </param>
```

The exception is:

```
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path
```

Comment: Dude. Show the exact code, i.e. the path in the XML and the path to your JAR file.

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the xml file, what exactly do u mean by the path to JAR?

Comment: Isn't it that you find the XML in the jar archive but have problem loading the files mentioned in the XML? Is that your problem?

Comment: actually, I make the JAR from my code. the xml file is a part of my code. It works fine before making a JAR

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. My question is what your problem is? Is your problem that you do not find the XML file after packing the code into jar? Or is your problem that you find the XML file after packing the code into jar but you do not find the files referenced from the XML?

Comment: I find the XML file after packing the code into jar but I do not find the files referenced from the XML

Comment: Ok, we need to specify your question yet more precisely. You do not find the files because after you pack the code into jar and ship the jar the files are not present on the file system at all?  Or the files are somewhere on the file system but you just cannot load them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69399/discussion-between-user3288346-and-michal).